# MongoDB, projecting values on group

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, aggregation

I have the following database

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60af57782fbbe971834ae2a6"
  },
  "order_id": 2539329,
  "user_id": 1,
  "order_number": 1,
  "order_dow": 2,
  "order_hour_of_day": 8,
  "products": [
    {
      "product_id": 196,
      "product_name": "Soda",
      "aisle_id": 77,
      "aisle": "soft drinks",
      "department_id": 7,
      "department": "beverages",
      "add_to_cart_order": 1
    },
    {
      "product_id": 12427,
      "product_name": "Original Beef Jerky",
      "aisle_id": 23,
      "aisle": "popcorn jerky",
      "department_id": 19,
      "department": "snacks",
      "add_to_cart_order": 3
    },
    {
      "product_id": 14084,
      "product_name": "Organic Unsweetened Vanilla Almond Milk",
      "aisle_id": 91,
      "aisle": "soy lactosefree",
      "department_id": 16,
      "department": "dairy eggs",
      "add_to_cart_order": 2
    },
    {
      "product_id": 26088,
      "product_name": "Aged White Cheddar Popcorn",
      "aisle_id": 23,
      "aisle": "popcorn jerky",
      "department_id": 19,
      "department": "snacks",
      "add_to_cart_order": 4
    },
    {
      "product_id": 26405,
      "product_name": "XL Pick-A-Size Paper Towel Rolls",
      "aisle_id": 54,
      "aisle": "paper goods",
      "department_id": 17,
      "department": "household",
      "add_to_cart_order": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to count the number of distinct products per AISLE using the aggregation framework.

I unwinded products, and then I group by product_id and product_name, my idea was to then project "aisle_id" and "aisle_name" to perform another grouping and do {"$sum": 1} to get the total number of product per aisle.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$products"},
    {"$group": {"_id": {"p_id": "$products.product_id", "p_name": "$products.product_name"}}},
    {"$project": {"products.aisle_id": 1, "products.aisle": 1}},
    {"$group": {"_id": {"a_id": "$products.aisle_id", "a_name": "$products.aisle"}, "prod per aisle": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

However it was unsuccesful, as the projecting doesnt actually project the aisle id and name onto the result, therefore the grouping is void...
How would I do that? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Query

- this groups by `aisle_id` and `product_id` counts, and keeps the aisle name and product name also
- finding the count of the unique `products` for each `aisle`

*i am not sure what you need if this isn't what you need if you can add the expected output

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=639621ca424f6130d7f1217c)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": "$products"},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": 
     {"aisle_id": "$products.aisle_id",
      "product_id": "$products.product_id"},
    "aisle": {"$first": "$products.aisle"},
    "product_name": {"$first": "$products.product_name"},
    "quantity": {"$count": {}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"_id": "$$REMOVE",
    "aisle_id": "$_id.aisle_id",
    "product_id": "$_id.product_id"}}])
```